# Converting octave matrix function in Mathematica

Tags: image-processing, wolfram-mathematica, octave

I'm trying to solve a problem: I need to translate an octave code in mathematica but I'm struggling with those lines.

```
function g = NeumannBoundCond(f)
[nrow,ncol] = size(f);
g = f;
g([1 nrow],[1 ncol]) = g([3 nrow-2],[3 ncol-2]);  
g([1 nrow],2:end-1) = g([3 nrow-2],2:end-1);          
g(2:end-1,[1 ncol]) = g(2:end-1,[3 ncol-2]);
```

Where f is defined as follows:

```
c0=2;
initialLSF = c0*ones(size(Img));
initialLSF(25:35,20:25)=-c0; 
initialLSF(25:35,40:50)=-c0;
f=initialLSF;
```

What Could be the Mathematica equivalent?
Thanks in advance.

P.S.
What is even the correspondent function of

```
[Ix,Iy] = gradient[Img];
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the post here: [Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/122362-could-anyone-please-explain-this-matlab-code), this should do for the first part:-

```
NeumannBoundCond[f_] := Module[{g},
   g = f;
   g[[{1, -1}]] = g[[{3, -3}]];
   g[[All, {1, -1}]] = g[[All, {3, -3}]];
   g];

MatrixForm[m = Partition[Range[56], 7]]
```

[image]

```
MatrixForm@NeumannBoundCond[m]
```

[image]